# Is there a way to implement the search provider override in a Firefox Web Extension?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to migrate some Chrome extensions to Firefox. One of them uses the following code in the manifest.json file for chrome:

```
"chrome_settings_overrides" : {
    "search_provider" : {
        "alternate_urls" : [],
        "encoding" : "UTF-8",
        "favicon_url" : "",
        "image_url" : "",
        "image_url_post_params" : "",
        "instant_url" : "",
        "instant_url_post_params" : "",
        "is_default" : true,
        "keyword" : "",
        "name" : "",
        "search_url" : "",
        "search_url_post_params" : "",
        "suggest_url" : "",
        "suggest_url_post_params" : ""
    }
},
```

I can't seem to find a similar setting for Firefox in their documentation. Does anyone know if there is such a thing for Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this will be implemented but the developers are still undecided as to how.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1301315